# Paypal payflow layout c don't see CANCEL link on magento website

Tags: magento, layout, paypal, hosted

I added layout c payflow option to my magento website and can modify everything and it works fine, except on the website I don't see the cancel link. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Esteban, when you say you don't see a cancel link, where are exactly are you expecting it at? The Iframe itself? There is a cancel return URL that you define your manager account but that is for layout A/B and not for C. There is only a redirect URL set. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: Hello, @GeekNinja That is exactly what I'm asking about. And I'm using layout C. When I set it up in my paypal manager account, Paypal dev. guide offers a workaround for layout C, if you add DISPLAY_URL before the return link- the cancellation link shows up on the frontend. I see it on the preview screen. I see a field to enter the credit card information and below it there is a cancel link. But when I implement it to my magento store, the whole iframe is there with the credit card information fields but there is no cancel link below it. No idea why and can't figure it out.

Comment: can you send me that direct link that describes that and a shot of what you're actually doing?

Comment: I actually figured it out today. Display_url was blocked by CancelUrl from Payflowlink.php. Once I deleted it, Cancel link showed up in checkout.

Comment: ah, ok. cool beans. Glad you got it